# Find the slope of a line given a point and an angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to figure out this problem and feel like it's something that must be so simple that I could've done in high school no problem, but for some reason my brain is frozen this morning.  I would really appreciate any help, and want to say thanks in advance. I tried to draw a picture below; I want to find the slope of a line given a point $(x,y)$ and $\theta$.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\tan \left( \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) - \theta\right)$ is the slope $m$.

Then use "point slope formula" (if you want an equation of the line, that is...)

$y-y_1 = m(x - x_1)$

---

For variety, I'll explain.

Labeling the origin "$O$" and the point $(x, y)$ "$P$", the segment $\overline{OP}$ makes an angle of $\tan^{-1} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ with the positive x-axis. But this is the sum of $\theta$ and the angle $\phi$ that your line makes with the positive x-axis (since we have opposite interior angles).

So $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) - \theta = \phi$.

Finally, $\tan \phi = m$.

Comment: Thanks for such quick answers. I think I'm still confused about, what if x is 0?

Comment: If X is 0, arctan(y/x) is 90 degrees. Thus, the formula turns out to be tan(90-$\theta$). You can think of it as pivoted at the Y axis at the point (0,y). Now, as you change $\theta$ from 0 to 90, the angle of the slope of your line changes from inf (Line parallel to X axis) to 0 (Y axis).

Comment: If $x=0$, then consider $m = \tan (90- \theta)$

Comment: Thanks again, sorry one more question, just to clarify... so, if x is 0, how do we compute arctan(y/x) without dividing by zero?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I maybe should have said, I'm trying to write code to do this, and it looks like there's an "atan2" function that checks for a special case like this. Thanks again

Comment: From how I see it, you can approach it asymptotically and state that arctan(y/x) is 90. You could have a certain eps ball around 0 which has 90 as its atan.

Comment: @all-too-human: In fact, atan2 is usually the primitive that the hardware can compute, and runtime libraries then implement the classical atan function as $\mathrm{atan2}(x,1)$.

Comment: To obtain $\overline{OP}$, type \overline{OP} in math mode.

Answer (score 5):

Another method:
If you know the exterior angle theorem, 
you know that The exterior angle is the sum of remote interior angles
thus:

$ \tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x} = \theta +  $ unknown angle

thus,

$ \tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x} - \theta =  $ unknown angle

$ \tan(\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x} - \theta )=   \tan( $unknown angle)

$$ \tan(\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x} - \theta )=   Slope$$

Answer (score 0):

The slope is given by the change in y for a given change in x. From trig, you have that the tangent of an angle in a right triangle is the measure of the side of the triangle opposite the angle divided by the measure of the side adjacent to the angle (not the hypotenuse).
See [diagram](https://skitch.com/tonymcdaniel/g62e6/trig).

Then you have
$$
\tan\theta = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}
$$
which is the slope of the line.

Answer (score -1):

find slope of the line you know as m1. m2 will be the slope of the unknown line and Ө the angle. The eqn tan(Ө) = (m2 - m1)/ (1 + (m1*m2))

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how your answer actually answers the question on the top.