# Find the slope of intercecting line given angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

My question is very similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105770/find-the-slope-of-a-line-given-a-point-and-an-angle), but I don't know how to modify the answer for an angle not relative to the origin. It's been way to long since math class.

If I have the line that passes through two points, lets say `1,3` and `5,3`, and intersects a line at `5,3` with an angle `θ`, how do I calculate the slope of the second line? The formula given (`tan(arctan(y/x)−θ)`) assumes the angle has a relation to the `x` axis, but I need a more general formula.

---

This image should illustrate the case.

I have known line, and a point at which it intersects another line. If I know the angle formed by the two lines, how can I find the slope of the second line.

[image]

Comment: Draw a picture!

Comment: @DavidH Done. Let me know if that's clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

θ is given by $tan θ = | \frac {m – M} {1 + mM} |$

From θ = 100 degrees, tan θ is a known quantity H, say.

M, the slope of the line passing through (0, 10) and (10, 0) = … = –1

Therefore, $H = \frac {m + 1} {1 – m}$

:

$m = … = \frac {H – 1} {H + 1}$

Note: In case θ = 100 degrees, it is necessary to use the supplementary angle (80 degrees) instead to make sure that both sides are positive.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow `m-M`. What is `M`? The slope of the first line? Is the formula `m = ( tan(θ) -1) / ( tan(θ) + 1)`?

Comment: M is the slope of the line passing through (0, 10) and (10, 0). To find M, use the formula M = (0 - 10)/(10 - 0) and you get M = -1.

Comment: L(1), the line passing through (0, 10) and (10, 0) has a slope = M = ... =–1. L(2) is your dotted line and it has a slope = m. If L(1) and L(2) cut each other at angle θ, then the relation between (m, M, θ) is given by the formula as quoted. ‘m – M’ simply means ‘n minus M’. Since M and θ are known quantities, through that formula, we can obtain the value of m exactly like what you have quoted in your comment. You have to let θ be 80 degrees though.

Comment: So then I just do the same thing a second time for another 20 degrees then, to get the 100 degree line slope?

Comment: Also, for a more general formula, is it `m = ( tan(θ) + M) / ( tan(θ) - M)`?

Comment: The answer to your first comment is no. If L(1) cuts L(2) at an angle of 100 degrees, then it is equivalent to say they cut each other at 80 degrees (because 100 + 80 = 180). Thus, after plugging in the 80 for the θ, the answer so obtained is therefore final.

Comment: Regarding your 2nd comment, assuming that m > M, according to my calculation, m = ( M + tan(θ)) / ( 1 - M tan(θ))

Comment: What if `m < M`?

Comment: I'm also not sure I understand your first comment. If I draw a second dotted line through `10,0` at 80 degrees it would have a slightly larger slope than `m`. The lines would not be the same.

Comment: m > M means requiring m is larger than M. This is to make sure that m - M is positive (there is an absolute sign in the original formula). L(1) cuts L(2) at TWO angles, one is 100 and the other is 80. They are adjacent to each other. Quoting the acute one (the 80 degrees one) will give the correct answer because (tan 80 = 5.67xxxx > 0, but tan 100 = - 5.67xxx, which is negative.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my "what if" comment. I meant if the formula only works for `m > M`, then what formula would I use when that isn't true (Such as in the reverse case, when I have `m` and am looking to find `M`).

Comment: The original formula can be interpreted as tan θ = $+\frac {m – M} {1 + mM}$....[1] or tan θ = $-\frac {m – M} {1 + mM}$....[2]. The object is to have the RHS positive (so is the LHS). Using the 'correct' one will give you θ = 80 and the other will give you 100.

Comment: @Tyrsius Glad to hear that you understand that there are 2 formulas. Your latest comment was sent to my global mailbox and that is why the complete message cannot be read. I only know that you are having some new trouble but what is it? If you want, you can contact me directly at ykw25781331@yahoo.com.hk