# Slope of an Angled Line Intersecting a Tangent Line

Tags: calculus, geometry

I know that to find the slope of a tangent line at a point $(x, y)$ the general form is $y-y_1 = f'(x_1)(x-x_1)$, and the equation of a line perpendicular to that tangent line is $y-y_1 = -\frac{1}{f'(x_1)} (x-x_1)$. So my question is, what is the general form for an equation that intersects the tangent line of a function at an angle of $\theta$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The perpendicular line has slope -1/f'(x) (the "negative reciprocal")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically asking for this: [Find the slope of a line given a point and an angle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105770/find-the-slope-of-a-line-given-a-point-and-an-angle)

The slope of the tangent line is f'(x). The angle between an arbitrary slope is $\tan^{-1}(f'(x)) - \theta$, so the slope must be tan of that value.

$$m = \tan(\tan^{-1}(f'(x)) - \theta)$$

and from point slope form we get:
$$y-y_1 = \tan(\tan^{-1}(f'(x)) - \theta) (x-x_1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Another formula is $\frac{tan(\theta) + f'(x_1)}{1 - tan(\theta)*f'(x_1)}$, which comes from the tangent sum formula. The new slope is the tangent of the rotation by $\theta$ of the angle of the original line with the horizontal. So the equation for the line is $y-y_1 = \frac{tan(\theta) + f'(x_1)}{1 - tan(\theta)*f'(x_1)}*(x-x_1)$.